# What is the correct CSS syntax for placing borders around a plotly-generated scatter plot matrix?

Tags: css, plotly, r-plotly

The individual scatter plots in my plotly SPLOM are identified as "rect.nsewdrag.drag" when I inspect the page. How can I draw borders around these elements?
[image]

I was thinking it would be something like this:

```
.rect.nsewdrag.drag {
     border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading `.`. The `rect` is an element (not a class):

```css
rect.nsewdrag.drag {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```